# How do the nodes affect the circuit?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, batteries

[image]

I am tasked to simplify this circuit to one source and one resistor, which is equivalent to the original but obviously easier to solve.

My problem is the fact, that I don't know how the nodes A and B affect the process. I'm more used to the circuits where the A and B nodes are on one end of the circuit, but these are in the middle. Not sure how this is supposed to be interpreted.

Comment: The output is across A-B. So you need to decide how to deal with Norton vs Thevenin to make one simplified source. How it is drawn is kind of irrelevant except that you are not used to the way it is drawn. If you want, move the current source and R3 to the left of A/B.

Answer (score 0):

A and B are not nodes, they are terminals. Everything connected to A by a wire is part of a single node. Similar for B. You may move the terminals to whatever location on the diagram you wish, as long as you keep each connected to its node. Same for the other components. Moving things around to make relationships clearer is a very useful tool of circuit analysis.

Comment: And, sadly, in intro courses they tend to try and obfuscate the problem with poorly drawn diagrams. That tends to confuse more than educate, but I digress...

Comment: @JonCuster They start with diagrams. Should make physical circuits first, then diagram them.

Comment: My son's circuits class had neither a lab nor use of a circuit simulator. I was appalled, but such is the state of many engineering schools nowadays. And funky diagrams to make the problem harder or more confusing. It didn't take very long for him to learn to redraw the circuit 'properly' to get at the answer.

Comment: @JonCuster Sigh. While university classes fail to teach in any practical way, I'm building Snap Circuits with my 7 year old granddaughter.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how exactly to merge the two sources (1) ideal current and voltage source J and (2) the voltage source so that the total current and voltage remain the same. However, if you need to make sure that the same source flows through a resistor into terminals A and B, I would suggest a linear circuit with the source flowing into a resistor with the resistance of (R1 + R2 + R3) ohms directly into a parallel structure of two branches: terminals A and B.

Essentially, the same amount of electricity is flowing through the same resistance into the two terminals, which, I think, is equivalent to what you are trying to do.

Here is a visual representation (I'm sorry its so unprofessional):

[image]